# На чём написан Brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide, sdk, app

Вот вопросик возник, на чём написан `Brackets`, понятно что сам интерфейс - это HTML, а судя по структуре, ядро на `Node.JS`. Но что-то я пока не слышал про такие комбинации, как я понял это не `AIR`. В общем вопрос в том, как пишутся такие приложения, есть какое-то `IDE` для сборки таких программ или `SDK`?

Comment: Исходник-то открыт, почему не посмотреть самому: https://github.com/adobe/brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets IDE написан на HTML+JS и упакован в этакий компактный Хром с помощью Brackets Shell (BS). Код BS тоже открыт (https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell), поэтому можно его использовать для написания своих десктопных приложений на HTML+JS под Мак, Виндовс и Линукс.

Сам BS основан на технологии CEF3 (Chromium Embedded Framework), у которой тоже открыт код (https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef).

Еще на эту тему рекомендую посмотреть Awesomium - тоже форк Хрома, позволяющий паковать свой HTML+JS в EXE и APP файлы.

Comment: Да я вобщем то подозревал что они используют CEF, но я надеялся что есть какая-то IDE чтобы можно было собирать программы не вручную а как то более автоматизированно

Comment: В дополнение: сейчас набирают популярность [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/) и [electron](http://electron.atom.io/), редактор [Atom](https://atom.io/) построен как раз на electron.